# Can I use Pages to authorize on my website in the same way Facebook Connect does?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authorization, fbconnect

Is there any way to authorize user (acting as a Page or Page administrator) in the same like FB Conect does but using Page data?

E.g. I would like a company, say local barber, authorize in my system as a certain Page (can be indirect, i.e. through a private account but I would like to know if this user is a page administrator). The purpose of this is to link an account on my website with a certain business that has representation on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could ask the user for manage_pages permission and look if the page you’re interested in is amongst them, but since that’ll give your app also their page access tokens, I doubt they’ll grant you that.

Less intrusive and much simpler would be to have them install your app on their page as a page tab, and then look into the signed_request parameter once their using your app - it has a boolean flag for wether the user is admin or not. After that they can remove your app again.